# When Adam delved and Eve span, Who was then the gentleman?

Tags: phrase-meaning

My understanding is that "[who was then the gentleman](https://victorianweb.org/art/design/morris/4.html#:%7E:text=John%20Ball%20remarked%20on%20the,to%20the%20needs%20of%20others%2C)" in "When Adam delved and Eve span, Who was then the gentleman?" has to do with the 1381 peasant rebellion, but could someone help me understand the meaning of this particular phrase? I found a Stack exchange link that explains "[gentleman](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/when-adam-delved-and-eve-span-who-was-then-the-gentleman)" in this case signifies a man of means, of good family and distinction, but again I don't see the connection between the word or the phrase with the rebellion. Thank you!

Comment: You apparently understand the sentence's literal meaning, so this question seems off-topic here. Perhaps the [history site](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit.

Comment: This question is off-topic, but you can read a bit more of the speech quoted [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ball_(priest)#Biography), which should make it clearer: "if God would have had any bondmen from the beginning, He would have appointed who should be bond, and who free." (bondmen=slaves, serfs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A “gentleman” was generally a landowner (or at least of a landowning family), who lived on rents; anyone doing manual labor, such as delving (digging) or spinning yarn, would disqualify himself from the status of gentleman.  The point is that there were no distinctions of social rank in the beginning, implying that they were not instituted by God.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your detailed explanations!